# Find largest number in an unsorted integer array of infinite size

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I am unable to find right approach for this problem. For sorted infinite array the common approach used is:

To find bounds and then apply respective operation for largest element search.

Let low be pointing to 1st element and high pointing to 2nd element of array, Now compare key with high index element,
->if it is greater than high index element then copy high index in low index and double the high index.
->if it is smaller, then apply the right operation.

However, what if array is unsorted.

Comment: If the array is of inifinite size, your task will never terminate - at any given time you have checked a finite number of integers only - the next one could be larger than whatever you've encountered so far. If the integers are bounded, you are lucky if the upper bound does occur in the array. in any case, there is no better method than a linear scan.

Comment: If by "infinite" you mean very large you could just read the array in in chucks, find the local max and carry that forward until you find the global max iterating one value at a time. If the the array is infinite it's not possible unless theres some other assumption

Comment: "infinite" does not make sense. You can find out about sorted vs unsorted by looking up Binary Search vs Linear Search.

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate over the array, storing the largest read value as you go but as the array is infinite it could take you infinity to find the actual answer. It's not really an algorithm question.

Comment: Since its infinite array, wont we have stack overflow if the largest element is more than the MAX integer count?

Comment: You wouldn't because you'd only be storing the value of the largest number in memory. Unless you want to be storing the position.

Comment: Got it. Another thing, wont the program have any issues during iteration. Also how will you define the limit of array size? For eg : please refer this link :           https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-position-element-sorted-array-infinite-numbers/

Comment: Your original question was about an infinite array. Hence you can't define an array size. The link you sent is about an infinite sorted array which is also a different question.

Comment: @aditya The link you posted is about finding an element with a specific value, not about finding the largest element as you wrote in the title. So which of these are you actually trying to do?